# How to call a method every time, when player stay at any collider?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a game like CubeSurfer. When player goes through an collectable, two methods are called (for "jumping" and creating a cube under player). But, when player goes through second, or third collectable, nothing happens. I tried to attached script to collectable, and tried to put the method "OnTriggerEnter" in the body of methods "Start" and "Update". But it doesn't work.

```
   using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCollider : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] Collider player;
    [SerializeField] GameObject destroyIt;
    [SerializeField] GameObject objToClone;
    [SerializeField] Transform rootObjInScene;
  

    Transform curParent;
    Vector3 posOffset, posPlayer;
    float distance = 1f;

    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider player)
    {
        PlayerJumping();
        CreateAnother();
        Destroy(destroyIt);
    }


    public void PlayerJumping()
    {
        posPlayer = Vector3.up * distance;
        Vector3 playerPos = rootObjInScene.position + posPlayer;
        rootObjInScene.transform.position = playerPos;
    }

    public void Awake()
    {
        curParent = rootObjInScene;
        posOffset = Vector3.down * distance;
    }

    public void CreateAnother()
    {
        Vector3 newPos = curParent.position + posOffset;
        GameObject newObj = Instantiate(objToClone, newPos, Quaternion.identity, curParent);

        curParent = newObj.transform;
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean like using [`OnTriggerStay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerStay.html) ? ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. You shouldn't call `OnTriggerEnter` explicitly (in your Update()), it's an event message and gets called automatically by unity when you enter a `Collider` marked `isTrigger`.
2. You can use `OnTriggerEnter` only if your `collider` is marked `isTrigger`, if you want to get a collision with a `Collider` that is not explicitly a trigger, you use `OnCollisionEnter`
3. To execute a method repeatedly while touching a `Collider` use `OnCollisionStay`, while touching or inside a `Collider` with `isTrigger` use `OnTriggerStay`

[OnCollisionStay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionStay.html)

[OnTriggerStay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerStay.html)

Comment: I tried "OnTriggerEnter" and it's allright, only when I attached one cube (I have 3 cubes in scene like collectable, and the code work only with one cube, it may be first, second or third, but nex cube not working). I tried also with RigidBody + OnCollisionEnter, and then it's bad. First time the scripts work alright, but the second cube,the script, that I need to start when player attached collectable, works with problems. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

You should also check your `Rigibody` collision detection mode in the inspector.

By default, this is set to `Discrete`, but if your object is fast-moving, you should set it to `Continuous` or `ContinuousDynamic`, otherwise the collisions won't be registered because the object is moving too quickly.

These are a little bit performance intensive, so I'd still recommreading up on the [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-collisionDetectionMode.html) or digging through a couple of good [articles](https://blog.terresquall.com/2019/12/collision-detection-modes-in-unitys-rigidbody-component/) to know what's best for you :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use OnCollisionStay or OnTriggerStay

```
void OnCollisionStay(Collision collisionInfo)
{
    //Do something when collisionInfo.gameObject stay in this.gameObject collider
}
```

Comment: I tried both. They work only when I "pick" one collectable.